# How to print half right side of sphere pattern in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to print right side of sphere, please suggest me an idea to print
expected output. I have added my program below which i can print first row how do i print rest. Thanks in advance...!!

**My program**

```
public class PatternRight {
    public static void main(String[] stars)
    {
        int size =5;
        for(int col=0;col<=size;col++)
        {
            System.out.print(" *");


        }
    }

}
```

**Actual output**

```
 * * * *
```

**Expected output**

```
* * * *
  * * *
    * *
      *
    * *
  * * *
* * * *
```

How do i print the rest of rows..?

Comment: Consider nested loops, where the inner loop compares the variable of the outer loop to determine if a space or asterisk is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely not the best way however it gets the work done!
If you want people to help you, try being polite next time.

```
for(i=4;i>=1;i--)
    {
        for(j=4;j>i;j--)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(k=1;k<=i;k++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    for(i=2;i<=4;i++)
    {
        for(j=4;j>i;j--)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(k=1;k<=i;k++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks much @Gaurav bro a i am new to java, not sure how to begin with, thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @RaviNarayanan no problem buddy.